# Correct way to create a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am reading two ways of creating a **JFrame** and i don't clearly undersand with is better or the differences:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyFramePanel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame myFrame = new JFrame("MyFramePanel");
....
```

And this one i find in some books:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ButtonFrame **extends JFrame**{

    public ButtonFrame() {
        super("Button Frame");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ...
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ButtonFrame bf = new ButtonFrame();
    }
}
```

I am going to use the first one -i found it in Stackoverflow- but i wonder why the most of the books i am reading about Java are using the "extends JFrame" one.

Thank you so much and sorry for bothering if my question is stupid.

Answer (score 6):

The first one is a good choice. Think about [Composition over Inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

> To favor composition over inheritance is a design principle that gives the design higher flexibility, giving business-domain classes and more stable business domain in the long term.

If you won't use your `MyFramePanel` inside a `JFrame`, but instead in an `Applet`, it's easier to switch and better to maintain in the long term.